# Brand and local products in single category magento

Tags: php, magento

I am working on magento project where I need two tabs on category page named "brand","local" just like http://www.fashionara.com/men/tees-polos.html .Can someone please guide me how can I do that ? any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Irphan

Comment: anybody there can answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter products and come with a collection using product attributes is the best way.

You create an attribute is_branded for product. While products data entry is done make sure you fill this value with Yes or No.

Now use this in your collection as filter.

make sure this attribute is configured to be filterable.As you need this in flat table.

Other option is that when flat table is being populated you populate an additional field(is_branded) so not data entry is needed.
Or when a product is being created then using some before save event observer make out whether its branded or local and populate this value so as to be saved when product is saved.

Comment: Thank you so much for this help.Now I got an idea from your answer.